# Forcing latex to handle home-made .ps files in an intelligent way

Tags: postscript

I write papers in latex and write figures as PostScript programs.  (The latter is not as crazy as it sounds, but that's a topic for elsewhere.)

My question is about the most intelligent way to get LaTeX to incorporate my homemade `.ps` pictures.  There are several options that are short of ideal:

1. Use `latex` then `dvips` then `ps2pdf` and include graphics by

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics{my_ps_file.ps}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This works, but the `ps2pdf` step on a file with lots of figures is very time-consuming.  (It has been on the order of a minute on a fast computer for some papers.  Small `.ps` files can have a lot in them because PostScript is a complete programming language.)
2. Manually do `ps2pdf` on each `.ps` file

   ```
   ps2pdf -dEPSCrop -dNOSAFER my_ps_file.ps
   ```

   then use `pdflatex`

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics{my_ps_file.pdf}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This works too, but there is the extra command-line step for every `.ps` file that has been modified since your last run of `pdflatex`.
3. Use pdflatex and graphics rules

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
   \epstopdfsetup{suffix=}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.ps}{pdf}{.pdf}{`ps2pdf -dEPSCrop -dNOSAFER #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}
   \begin{document}
   \includegraphics{my_ps_file}
   \end{document}
   ```

   The 5th line tells LaTeX that when it sees `\includegraphics{my_ps_file}`, it should look for a file `my_ps_file.ps`.

   The 6th line tells LaTeX how to handle `my_ps_file.ps`:
   In order of the arguments, when (1) it sees a `.ps` file, it should eventually expect to have a `.pdf` file to insert, (3) it should read bounding box information from the `.pdf` file, and (4) it should run a certain command on the `.ps` file to get the `.pdf` file.

   The package `epstopdf` is used here only so that I can use the 4th line `\epstopdfsetup{suffix=}`, which tells LaTeX to call the `.pdf` file `my_ps_file.pdf` rather than `my_ps_file-ps-converted-to.pdf`.

   This works, and it automatically runs `ps2pdf` on `my_ps_file.ps file`, but only if it needs to:  if it sees that `my_ps_file.pdf` already exists, it uses `my_ps_file.pdf`.
   (To get this feature, we used `\includegraphics{my_ps_file}` instead of `\includegraphics{my_ps_file.ps}`).

   This possibility eliminates the slowness of possibility (1) and eliminates the extra command-line steps of possibility (2).  But unfortunately, it adds a new command-line step for every modified `.ps` file:  You have to manually remove `my_ps_file.pdf` every time you change `my_ps_file.ps` or else LaTeX will keep using the old `my_ps_file.pdf` rather than making a new one.

Now for the question:  The option I want, but don't know how to implement, would work just like (3), except that if `my_ps_file.pdf` is present and is newer than `my_ps_file.ps` LaTeX uses it, and otherwise runs `ps2pdf` on `my_ps_file.ps`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Err...is there no way to get your plot generating tool to spit out PDF in the first place? That's what I've done. Or when you say that you write figures in postscript your real mean that ***you*** write them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the full power of `epstopdf`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.ps}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.ps}{pdf}{.pdf}{ps2pdf -dEPSCrop -dNOSAFER #1 \OutputFile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{my_ps_file}
\end{document}
```

This will run the conversion program only if the target file (`.pdf`) is older than the source file. Remember to call `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` command line option.

Answer (score 3):

The current release of TeXlive does just this with `.eps` files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{tmp1}
\end{document}
```

I have a file `tmp1.eps`, but not `tmp1.pdf`, so the first run of `pdflatex` says

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-04-25 19:09:03
(epstopdf)                    size: 204851 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 4.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf tmp1.eps)...executed sa
fely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-05-11 13:09:38
(epstopdf)                    size: 64649 bytes.

<tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>
File: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
```

The second run just uses this file:

```
[2 <./tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>] (./tmp.aux) )
```

Now I change the postscript file: `touch tmp1.eps`, and `pdf` is regenerated:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-05-11 13:17:04
(epstopdf)                    size: 204852 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-05-11 13:16:39
(epstopdf)                    size: 64651 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 4.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf tmp1.eps)...executed sa
fely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2012-05-11 13:17:08
(epstopdf)                    size: 64651 bytes.

<tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 614.295pt x 794.97pt>
File: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
```

So save your PostScript files as `.eps` and check the system is intelligent enough to understand what you want.

Of course as the last resort you can use `make`: it knows how to check whether to regenerate dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55429/3083) by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) is the most pragmatic. For completeness I'd like to point out that for this kind of problem the [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) tool  was invented. A Makefile contains rules that invoke a tool when a source is more recent than the file that the tool derives from the source.

```
doc.pdf: psfile1.pdf psfile2.pdf psfile3.pdf
    pdflatex doc.tex

%.pdf: %.ps
    ps2pdf -dEPSCrop -dNOSAFER $<
```

The above code is just a sketch. It derives a pdf file from a ps file and states that your main pdf file depends on a number of files that are derived from ps files (by the second rule).

Compiling LaTeX documents with Makefiles is a little tricky because there might be other dependencies that are sometimes difficult to capture with Make. Another problem is that `pdflatex` might need to run several times.