# Strange output for a beamsplitter with xelatex

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I’m trying to figure out how to use the pst-optexp package. However I can’t make the `\beamsplitter` work. Even with the code provided by the documentation (*§4.20, p.46 of the English version of the documentation*):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(3,2)
\beamsplitter[beam](0,1)(2,1)(2,0){BS}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I obtain this strange output:

[image]

I use the 5.2 version of the package and I am working with TeX Live 2016. No error is showing up during the compilation.

The only (somehow could be) related comment I have found about this is the one of Christoph [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285437/118440) (below the answer)…

---

**Edit**

In fact by using the combination **latex>dvips>ps2pdf**, it works. However I would have liked to use XelateX if possible…

Comment: I think I am just going to include the ps file using this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55427/forcing-latex-to-handle-home-made-ps-files-in-an-intelligent-way

But if anyone has a better idea I am definitely interested :)

Comment: That looks indeed strange. Until now I was only aware of problems with the beam drawing, but here the square is not rotated... In any case, I don't know about the specialties of XeLaTeX, how to debug it and what would be required to make pst-optexp fully work with it. So I guess I won't be able to support it.